# Python "or" executes both left and right expressions

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def func(i):
    a = i + 1
    (a % 15 == 0 and print(f"{a} AB")) or print(a)

    i < 15 and func(a)
    
func(0)
```

The output is:

```
1
2
...
14
15 AB
15
16
```

I don't get why both `(a % 15 == 0 and print(f"{a} AB"))` and `print(a)` statements are executed when I am using `or` between them.

Any ideas?

**P.S:
Just a small clarification, because of the comments - this is just an exercise and not a real code that will be used in production ever**

Comment: Because the left side is not truthy.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: `print` returns `None` which is falsy.

Comment: okay, how to make the left side truthy then?

Comment: By writing proper `if-else` instead of inline `and-or` contraptions.

Comment: Don't use the `x and y or z` construction because as you discovered it's problematic. You can use `y if x else z` but it's most readable to use a simple `if` statement.

Comment: If you really want to do this the weird way, do `(a % 15 == 0 and (print(f"{a} AB") or True)) or print(a)`, however you should just use `if`/`else`

Comment: @luk2302 I intentionally am not using `if` and loops. I am exercising

Comment: Could also do a tuple like `(True, print("…"))` if you want an expression that evaluates as truthy while having a side effect.  But yeah, don’t do this, just write idiomatic code.

Comment: @luk2302 this will never be written in a production code, don't worry :)

Comment: Note that the `and/or` construction can be useful to execute some statements in a list comprehension (but for the sake of readability, it's better to use a for loop instead).

Comment: @Samathingamajig, thank you! Also, thank you all who actually described where the issue is - now I get it :)

Comment: If you need to use the `and/or` then it's cleaner to do that inside the print: `print(a % 15 == 0 and f"{a} AB" or a)`

Comment: I think the problem here is _not_ that you should never use inline `if / else` but that the purpose of an inline if expression is to produce a value. So the mistake here is mixing `print` calls into the inline if/else.  With the `print` calls you are only executing them for their _side-effect_ and don't care about their value (they return `None` as explained in other comments). So in this case the purpose of your if/else block is to execute the print calls rather than the produce a value, hence you should use if blocks instead.

Comment: Of course, another way to make the LHS truthy when it "should" be is just to add `not`. So `(a % 15 == 0 and not print(f"{a} AB")) or print(a)` would do what you want...

Answer (score 3):

Of course, as you already acknowledged, you really shouldn't write code like this. With that out of the way:

Let's simplify the code in your question:

```
(condition and print("A")) or print("B")
```

Now, `c = (a and b)` can be verbosely written as:

```
c = a
if c:
    c = b
```

and `c = (a or b)` can be written as:

```
c = a
if not c:
    c = b
```

So our simplified version can be written as:

```
or_left = condition
if or_left:
    or_left = print("A")
if not or_left:
    print("B")
```

Now what is the value of `or_left`? If `condition` is falsey, then so is `or_left`, but if it is truthy, then `or_left` gets assigned the return value of `print("A")`, which is `None` and thus falsey as well.

Thus `"B"` is always printed.

So how can we get the desired behaviour, while not using `if` statements or expressions?

Well, we somehow need to be able to evaluate `print("A")` and get a truthy value.

One way to do that would be to use a function that contains multiple statements.

For example:

```
def truthy_print(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)  # this None is thrown away
    return True

...
(condition and truthy_print("A")) or print("B")
```

Another way to do it is to wrap the `None` in another value, for example:

```
(condition and [print("A")]) or print("B")
```

Now what gets looked at for truthiness is a list containing a single element, which is always truthy. You could use other solutions too, like a tuple, a dictionary or set, or to use another `or`:

```
(condition and (print("A") or True)) or print("B")
```

---

Here's a challenge: can you write `func` as a single expression, like this: `func = lambda i: ...`?